# Trying to parse String to DateTime into format "02/01/2010" dd/MM/yyyy rather than "1/2/2010 MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, types, casting

I am trying to convert a string into date time format.

```
DateTime.Parse(tempfrmBankDetails.dgvBankDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells["PaymentDate"].Value.ToString(),null);
```

This is printed as an output but i want it in dd/MM/yyyy format. How should i parse it
    {1/2/2010 12:00:00 AM}
**EDIT**

I have created a custom control which accepts string input and their i am using mask as "00/00/2\000".
Here i have done all the validation into my control so as to accept all valid date but they should be only in format dd/MM/yyyy. That's why i want to convert it into string

Comment: Just out of interest, can't you just store the value as a DateTime and retrieve that instead? Why are you doing `.ToString()`?

Comment: here's some more info: http://blog.stevex.net/parsing-dates-and-times-in-net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string stringValue = tempfrmBankDetails.dgvBankDetails.SelectedRows[0]
    .Cells["PaymentDate"].Value.ToString();
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(stringValue, "M/d/yyyy");

// use this when you need to show that formatted date value
string formattedDate = dateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.ParseExact